# can't able to get current url in python

Tags: python, django

I have created a class and method as like below. I need to get current page url. But am getting error while calling get_full_path().

```
class A(object):
   def get_user(request):
       current_url = request.get_full_path()
   return current_url


class B(A):
    b = A()
    b.get_user()
    print b.current_url


Traceback Error:
    AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'get_full_path'
```

What mistake i did?

Comment: What is `get_user`? Is it a Django view? Also  your indentation is off.

Comment: You forget `self` argument in `get_user` definition.

Answer (score 2):

This code cannot work because has some misconceptions:

1. You should pass `request` to `get_user`
2. First argument of `get_user` should be `self` which points to *A* instance.
3. Object cannot return value (you have `return current_url` in *A* `class`).
4. It is not necessary to use class inheritance in this example.

Your code should look like:

```
class A(object):
    current_url = None
    def get_user(self, request):
        self.current_url = request.get_full_path()

b = A()
b.get_user(request)
print b.current_url
```

Or if you want to pass full path to constructor of `class A`, and for whatever reason use it in inherited class B:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, current_url):
        self.url = current_url

    def get_path(self):
        return self.current_url

class B(A):
    # whatever you need here
    pass

b = B(request.get_full_path())
print b.get_path() # prints current path
```

Comment: No.. am trying to call this method to another class.. am getting error like name 'request' is not defined while calling the method.

Comment: @PythonTeam Yes, because probably `request` is not defined indeed. If you want to pass variable to method (`request` in this case) it should be defined. For instance, if you call `get_user` method in your view, then you have `request` variable passed as first argument to view function - so it is defined in function scope. Generally - you don't have access to request outside view.

Comment: Ho do i use it to get_full_path

Comment: @PythonTeam You can't in object/model. It doesn't make sense. Path is property of given request. Request instance is available only in view. If you want to have request in your object/model, you have to pass it manually from your view to object method or constructor, ie. like in my example above.

Comment: is it possible to use __init__ as constructor and get full path in it and to use it to another class