# Issue to call method of variable from another class

Tags: python, django

I am not able to call method from another class. I am getting error as request is not defined, while calling the method.As per discussion i tried calling the method from another class like get_user(request). And tried to access the variable from another class

```
class A(object):
    def get_user(self,request):
        a = self.request.get_full_path()

class B(A, AllowEmptyMixin, AutoModelSelect2Field):
   b = A()
   b.get_user(request) ---->>> Getting error "request" is not defined
```

Can anyone clear my issue

Comment: What do you expect to be passed to `get_user()`?

Comment: @PythonTeam after seeing your [other question on python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792644/cant-able-to-get-current-url-in-python). I mean no disrespect but you may want to consider checking out a basics of python tutorial. The code you're writing doesn't make a whole lot of logical sense.

Comment: Why would you ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792644/cant-able-to-get-current-url-in-python) again?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792644/cant-able-to-get-current-url-in-python

Answer (score 2):

When you call `b.get_user(request)` you call `get_user` method and pass a variable called `request` there, but you don't have the 'request' variable in your current scope.

And I am not sure what exactly sure what your code supposed to do now.

Comment: especially when they end up pulling request out of `self` anyways.

Comment: I would like to get current url path which is in another class method.

Answer (score 0):

Change method `get_user` to use the method argument `request` instead of the non-existing `self.request` variable.

```
   class A(object):
        def get_user(self,request):
            a = request.get_full_path()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two place where code is break.

```
b.get_user(request) ---->>> Getting error "request" is not defined
```

there is no request variable in this scope.

and in the get_user(). There is no request argument in function. SO self.request will not work.